# Android: connect multiple BLE devices without using third party libraries

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am working on Android BLE Devices. Right now, I am trying to keep state connected of two BLE devices(eg. two Scales devices or Activity Sensor devices).

Well, I know I can do that by using multiple services where each service contains different BluetoothGatt object for different BLE devices. But I think that isn't a proper way.

Other option I found is managing two different BluetoothGatt objects within one service. But that would be quite complex for me right now.

I analyzed nRF Connect App. In that, they are able to connect multiple BLE Devices using single BluetoothLEService.

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: *Is there any other way to solve this issue?* What issue? Where is a real question? *...But that would be quite complex...* programming is not easy

Comment: The problem is I want to connect two BLE devices at a same time using a single service.

Comment: Ok ... it is the problem ... but where is the question which fit StackOverflow? For now this question looks like: *Can someone implement what I want for free? I didn't tried anything and I think it is to complex for me* which doesn't fit StackOverflow

Comment: I am not saying I don't want it implemented free. I just want little help from anyone. I will try it my own. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Do you mean connecting two android BLE device or android device which connects to BLE enable embaded system device?

Comment: I am developing an Android Applciation in which I want to connect two BLE Devices like two activity sensor watches(you can assume it is a fitbit watch) at a same time.